# C# attribute collection

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I have a certain collection of built-in attributes (like System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializableAttribute) that I want to apply to a certain collection of classes

Is it possible to unite those attributes into one? I don't want to apply all of them to all of my classes explicitly (the attibute collection might change during the development process)

What I want is one attribute, e.g.

```
public class MyClassAttribute: System.Attribute { ... }
```

which I could apply easily to my classes

```
[MyClass]
public class SampleClass { ... }
```

and that would cause SampleClass to have Serializable attribute and others. Thanks

Comment: Maybe a good candidate for [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) ?

Answer (score 9):

No, it is not, basically. Actually, `[Serializable]` is *particularly* note-worthy because that has different treatment in the compiler - it is not written as an attribute, but as a raw flag (the runtime simply lies if you ask "does it have the `[Serializable]` attribute" - it checks the flag against the type, and returns what you *expect* to see, even though that isn't the truth).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible out of the box, but you could use [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) to modify the types in your assembly in a post-build step, removing your collection-attribute and adding the others.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I think a lot of the built-in attributes are sealed so this might not be possible.