# Group Stacked Attributes

Tags: c#, attributes

If I have multiple attributes on a method, and I have multiple methods with the same group of attributes, can I instead have a grouped attribute class which uses all of the attributes?

E.G, I have:

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(string))]
```

I'd rather have:

```
[HttpGetString]
```

Same could be applied to larger groups of attributes.

Comment: Sure! Just implement `HttpGetStringAttribute : Attribute` and include all of the logic for both `HttpGetAttribute` and `ResposneTypeAttribute`. Seriously though, your question is a bit broad. *Why* do you want to do that? To save 1 line of code? Put them both on one line: `[HttpGet, ResponseType(typeof(string))]`

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Considering the example, which are attributes that ASP.NET depends on to do certain things, would that really work? I mean, ASP.NET won't actually look for `HttpGetStringAttribute`.

Comment: @BartvanNierop: Very good point. OP would have to register the custom attribute and how to handle it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# attribute collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525323/c-sharp-attribute-collection)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, you can't. Not out of the box anyway.

The question was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17525481/2700399) by [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525323/c-sharp-attribute-collection).

However, you could modify your types as a post build step using [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17525476/2700399) by [Daniel Sklenitzka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869250/daniel-sklenitzka) in that same question.

Comment: Instead of linking to a duplicate (of a duplicate) as an answer, I would simply vote to close as a duplicate of the original answer.

Comment: I agree, but that requires 3k rep. =]

Comment: Although I guess I can flag it... I'll remove the answer once the question has been marked duplicate.