# Wrap attribute inside a custom attribute

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit.net

When using `Xunit`, I'd like to be able to put attribute `[UnitTest]` and `[IntegrationTest]` instead of `[Trait("Category", "Unit")]` and `[Trait("Category", "Integration")]`.

Usage would be like this then:

```
[Fact]
[UnitTest]
public async Task TestGetAreasForCompany()
{
  // Test code
}
```

I created 2 custom attributes but can't wrap my head around how to use them.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
[Trait("Category", "Integration")]
public class IntegrationTestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IntegrationTestAttribute()
    {
    }
}
```

Above doesn't work. Traits are not picked up.

Xunits implementation is as follows:

```
using System;
using Xunit.Sdk;

namespace Xunit
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Attribute used to decorate a test method with arbitrary name/value pairs ("traits").
    /// </summary>
    [TraitDiscoverer("Xunit.Sdk.TraitDiscoverer", "xunit.core")]
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public sealed class TraitAttribute : Attribute, ITraitAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of the <see cref="T:Xunit.TraitAttribute" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">The trait name</param>
        /// <param name="value">The trait value</param> 
        public TraitAttribute(string name, string value)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like it's impossible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525323/c-sharp-attribute-collection

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to solve it with [this article](https://mac-blog.org.ua/xunit-category-trait/), as Xunit provided a way to create your own category attributes.